# How to change object in state without making a copy

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, setstate

I have a products state object that is just for front-end ease, and I want to decrement a field, but when I do, it creates a *copy* of the object rather than mutate the actual object. What is the React-y way to manipulate the fields without duplicates?

My download function:

```
  const getDownload = async (id, uid, bucket_prefix, variation) => {
    const getPresignedUrl = functions.httpsCallable('getPresignedUrl')
    await getPresignedUrl({id: id, uid: uid, bucket_prefix: bucket_prefix ? bucket_prefix : '', variation: variation})
      .then(res => {
        if (Object.keys(res.data).length > 0) window.open(res.data, '_blank')
        const intendedObj = ownedProds[id]
        setOwnedProds({
          ...ownedProds,
          
        })
      })
      .catch(err => console.error(err))
  }
```

The shape of `ownedProds`:

```
ownedProds = {
  {id}: 
    {
    uid:
    id:
    downloads_remaining:
    ...
    } 
  }
}
```

I basically want to target `ownedProds[id]` in my setState, and just make the `ownedProds[id].downloads_remaining` to be one less. I can do it, but it just adds *another* object with the same id as a key in the object.

I *can* move getData outside of the useEffect and just call it again, but then it's pinging my server again and getting *all* data all over again, and the order gets messed up so there's a shift, and it's a PITA to sort objects just because I want to mutate *one* property of one object in the state object. Am I being silly? Should I just call the server again for a superfluous number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can achieve that by passing a function to setState. The function will receive the previous value, and return an updated value. So according to what you want to do something like this should work:

```
setOwnedProds(ownedProds => {
    ownedProds[id].downloads_remaining--;
    // Or any other state manipulation you want to achieve.
    return ownedProds;        
   });
```

Comment: That's crazy. I had *no* idea that if you passed the previous state, that you could access the properties like that. Or that you could just decrement like that. Hell yeah, it works! Thanks!